# Setting a method of web form to STAThread

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webforms, fingerprint

I am developing a web application in C# with VS 2012.

I have a fingerprint sensor with his dll in Windows Forms format. I am developing a web application, so I need to communicate the two projects.

But the fingerprint sensor needs an STAThread environment, as the windows forms one. How can I set the STAThread to a WebForm? I try this

```
    [STAThread]
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code of fingerprint
    }
```

but didn't work, I've got the exception ThreadStateException which says that the subprocess is not in a container of single-threaded. Help me! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that you can do that on the client (Web) simple way. I think that you can not do except webservice communicate with your device. I have made something like this but was for printer and i had use asmx service.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how I run a web service in STAThread?

Comment: On my case i used asmx service in order to send a print to the selected printer. In your case things might be different. You might create an activex control which will do that for you or silverlight component.

Comment: Actrivex or silverlight installed in client's machine. So i think you can access your device.

Comment: But if I can set the web service to STAThread, can I do the communication?

Comment: I am sorry but i don't know. For the printer works like harm. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use STAThread in a web app.

You better create a service, which stands between the fingerprint sensor and your web app.  The service will operate in STA, and expose methods for the webapp to use.

Comment: No, don't create a web-service.  Create a Windows Service:

Comment: Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx.